# cant use sublimerepl to debug ruby code

Tags: ruby, sublimerepl

When I run sublimeREPL with Ruby I got a message like this. It works fine Ruby(IRB deprecated)

/Users/paul/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Ruby/pry_repl.rb:37:in `': uninitialized constant Pry::InputCompleter (NameError)

***Repl Closed***

I am new to Ruby, if anyone can help me to solve it or give me a hint on whats going on I would be really appreciated.

If I run sublimeREPL with Python code I get

***Repl Closed***

if I hit enter next Sublime Text will close..

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/smiler/SublimeREPL/commit/95ffe15382336ef6720502752e71c290055cf7f8

this patch is fixed the 'InputCompleter' error, but when using 'help', it raise readline error.